# Understanding properties of conditional entropy

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, entropy, information-theory, conditional-entropy

I was trying to understand concept of cross entropy. Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Other_properties):

> 1. $H(Y|X)\leq H(Y)$
> 2. Although the specific conditional entropy $H(X|Y=y)$ can be either less or greater than $H(X)$ for a given random variate $y$ of $Y$, $H(X|Y)$ can never exceed $H(X)$

I want to have intuition about these two points. I think of them as follows:

1. $H(Y|X)\leq H(Y)$

   - $H(Y|X)<H(Y)$ when $Y$ is dependent on $X$, that is, knowing something about $X$ does indeed tell something about $Y$ and hence requires lesser information to describe $Y$ when $X$ is given.
   - $H(Y|X)=H(Y)$ when $Y$ is independent on $X$.
2. $H(X|Y=y)$ can be either less or greater than $H(X)$

   - $H(X|Y=y)<H(X)$ when $Y=y$ does indeed tell something about $X$
   - $H(X|Y=y)>H(X)$

     (i) when $Y=y$ does not tell anything about $X$ or

     (ii) when $Y$ is independent of $X$

Am I correct with above? Or completely screwed up? Also, I feel less confident about (i).